# How can i avoid the use of the auto specifier in range-based for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, auto, c++03

I am trying to use the auto specifier in the next loop

```
for (auto x : graf[nod])
{
    if (cost + x.second < dist[x.first])
    {
        dist[x.first] = cost+x.second;
        pq.push(make_pair(x.first, dist[x.first]));
    }
}
```

where graf is a vector of pairs, and it seems not to work in c++98, and i do not know how to turn it into a more usual kind of loop. Is there any way to avoid it ?

Comment: the equivalent syntax can be seen in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 3):

You might turn C++11

`for (auto x : graf[nod])`

into C++03

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != graf[nod].size(); ++i) {
    std::pair<T1, T2> x = graf[nod][i];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it's trivial for an `std::vector`.

Comment: That is the correct answer, but does it make sense though? To access a pair inside a vector it should be just  `for (auto x : graf)`?

Comment: @anastaciu - it does make sense, given that the question is about a version of C++ predating C++11 - which is the standard that introduced both the range-based for and `auto` type deduction.

Comment: @Peter, yes the answer is perfect, my doubts are about the OP access to the data.

Comment: @Peter: I think anastaciu's doubt is about mismatching about OP description (*"graf is a vector of pairs"*) and code `graf[node]` as container. (and I tend to use code as up-to-date documentation)

Answer (score 0):

Range for is not magic. It has a [definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for ( init-statement(optional)range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

Means

```
{
  init - statement 
  auto&& __range = range_expression;
  auto __begin = begin_expr;
  auto __end = end_expr;
  for (; __begin != __end; ++__begin) {
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
  }
}
```

`auto` isn't magic either. It is just a placeholder for the actual type.

Having said that, you can use [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/) to translate some of the shortcuts in modern C++ to more traditional concepts. For instance. This:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> graf;

  // fill graf

  for (auto x : graf[0]) {
    x.first += x.second;
  }
}
```

[Translates to](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHV0aWxpdHk+CiNpbmNsdWRlIDx2ZWN0b3I+CgppbnQgbWFpbigpIHsKICBzdGQ6OnZlY3RvcjxzdGQ6OnZlY3RvcjxzdGQ6OnBhaXI8aW50LCBpbnQ+Pj4gZ3JhZjsKCiAgLy8gZmlsbCBncmFmCgogIGZvciAoYXV0byB4IDogZ3JhZlswXSkgewogICAgeC5maXJzdCArPSB4LnNlY29uZDsKICB9Cn0=&insightsOptions=cpp2a,use-libcpp&std=cpp2a&rev=1.0):

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > > graf = std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >();
  {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > & __range1 = graf.operator[](0);
    std::__wrap_iter<std::pair<int, int> *> __begin1 = __range1.begin();
    std::__wrap_iter<std::pair<int, int> *> __end1 = __range1.end();
    for(; std::operator!=(__begin1, __end1); __begin1.operator++()) 
    {
      std::pair<int, int> x = std::pair<int, int>(__begin1.operator*());
      x.first += x.second;
    }

  }
}
```

`std::__wrap_iter` is an implementation detail, but besides that it's very clear what is going on.